# How do you keep a JButton from changing sizes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I was playing around with `JFrame` windows (since I'm new to Java) and I discovered that my `JButton` changed sizes when I manually maximized the `JFrame`. When I didn't maximize the screen it was still the size I had set it to.

Can I get any help?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Test Stuff\\icon.png");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(856, 482);
        frame.setLocation(384, 216);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.cyan );
        frame.setIconImage(icon);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton buttonClose = new JButton("Close");
        buttonClose.setSize(100, 50);
        buttonClose.setLocation(378, 10);
        buttonClose.addActionListener(e -> {
            frame.dispose();
        });
        buttonClose.setVisible(true);
        buttonClose.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(buttonClose);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `buttonClose.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(100, 50));`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setSize() or setBounds() or setPreferredSize().

Swing is designed to be used with layout managers.

You are using a FlowLayout. The FlowLayout will respect the size of the button.

The problem with your code is that you add the button to the frame AFTER the frame is visible, so initially the layout manager is not invoked and the buttonis displayed at the random size you set for it. When you maximize the frame the layout manager is invoked so the button is displayed at its preferred size.

Swing components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. So the basic order of your logic should be:

```
frame.add( button );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

and the button will be displayed at its proper size.

If you want "extra" space around the text of the button then you use properties of the button to control this:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
```